# What is the most standard/correct way to return logic error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

ASP.Net MVC 3, Kendo UI Web.

Typical example -- there is a database and some tables, user is editing the data -- adding new entries, deleting, updating.

Apart from technical problems (network connection down), there could be several logical ones -- for example user does not have permission to write anything, or there is a lock on data, or user tries to update something what was deleted meanwhile, and so on.

So I would like to return in such cases an error, so I could handle it with Kendo and display, let's say some alert dialog (JS `alert`).

Now -- what would be the most well designed way, most correct, to do so? I am not looking for "oh, well, it just works" approach.

Is throwing `HttpException` a good idea in such case (I have my issues with it, because it is **http** exception, and the error I try to pass has nothing to do with http really)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to work under assumption that you're using Kendo DataSource object which exists on most widgets in self-binding mode (has transport section defined and fires it's own CRUD requests).

The actions that your grid's CRUD is tied to, should be returning IEnumerable.ToDataSourceResult, on the model it received as input. If in your processing you detected errors, add them to ModelState via ModelState.AddModelError method which you can access in your action. The ToDataSourceResult will detect presense of any errors in ModelState object automatically and serialize them into the JSON response (errors field). You can then act on them via subscribing to DataSource.error even on the client side (see http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#error).

Comment: Thank you very much (also for reading between lines). One question though -- I assume the passing error via ModelState is a general solution, correct? *As for Kendo I have an issue with it (Kendo) -- the error handler is triggered, alert is shown, but despite it, the framework assumes there was no error at the same time (some contradiction) and blindly updates the control (so for delete for example -- in UI the row is deleted).*

Comment: I know what you mean and I ran into this myself, this is the primary reason why I don't use self binding with kendo. I ran into to many gotcha's and I often need to do a higher scale orchestration then what those features allow. Consider using MVVM pattern either using telerik's own MVVM framework or my personal favorite Knockout. For this particular scenario however, I would call transport.read to rebind the control to server data again using the "fresh" copy from database.